# Isnt in the header?

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I am trying to create the headers for a table. However it seems all the values from the for loop are not taken as headers.

This is the result I get

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is the code: </title>
</head>
<body>



    <?php
        echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:300px\">";

            echo "<tr>";

                echo "<th id=\"Cost\">Cost</th>";

                for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
                    echo "<th id='C.$i'>" + $_REQUEST['c'.$i] + "     </th>";
                }



            echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: + are not used to concate in PHP. You should have searched for this!

Answer (score 3):

Try to change [+] to [.]

```
       echo "<th id='C.$i'>" . $_REQUEST['c'.$i] . "     </th>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you explain why please?

Comment: @user3624883 In PHP, to add one string to another, the dot operator `.` is used rather than `+`.

Comment: @user3624883 To Clarify the `+` operator is not used in concatenation with PHP, rather this is a Javascript method to concatenate strings. PHP uses the period mark `.` to merge strings together